# "undefined is not a function" when create android native module in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, native-module

I'm following [ReactNative Native Module Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html) to write the java class that can be used in JS side. The exported method is `show` from class `ToastModule`(exported as `ToastAndroid`). The `show` method is below:

```
public void show(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
}
```

All work as expected with the toast button appear when I invoke ToastAndroid.show from Button onPress handler.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';

const ToastAndroid = NativeModules.ToastAndroid

export default class App extends Component {

handleBTNPressed(){
  ToastAndroid.show('Awesome', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
}
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcome}>
        Welcome to React Native!!
      </Text>
      <Button title='click me' onPress={()=>this.handleBTNPressed()}/>
    </View>
  );
 }
}
```

However, when I further change the function name from

```
@ReactMethod
public void show(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
}
```

to

```
@ReactMethod
public void showAgain(String message, int duration) {
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
}
```

I encounter the following error:"undefined is not a function"

[image]

this error shows again if I add a new exported method as following:

```
@ReactMethod
public void showAgain2(String message, int duration) {
    String mes = "Hi " + message;
    Toast.makeText(getReactApplicationContext(), message, duration).show();
}
```

Is there anyone know which step I goes incorrectly?

EDIT==========================

There might already be a `ToastAndroid` in ReactNative, so I change the name to `MyToastExample`. However, now the error become the following

[image]

Does anyone encounter the same issue?

Comment: have you run `react-native run-android` after you change the function name?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that but not work. Even if I keep the `show` method and change the display message for the toast, it won't take effect.

Comment: try clean --> rebuild

Comment: I have tried that but not work. Someone mentioned there might already `ToastAndroid` in ReactNative, so I change the name to `MyToastExample`, now the error become "undefined is not an object"(evaluating 'MyToastExample.show')

Comment: I had the same problem, it looks like a bad link. But the strange is that this is an oficial example.

Answer (score 0):

In [this step](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#register-the-module), check if you have import the right `ToastModule`, because ReactNative also have a class Called `ToastModule`.

Check if this line `import com.facebook.react.modules.toast.ToastModule;` exist in `*ReactPackage.java`

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using `import` instead of `require`.

In my situation, I was using:

```
var Contacts = require( "react-native-unified-contacts" );
```

and I was getting the `undefined is not function` error.

However, changing to:

```
import Contacts from "react-native-unified-contacts";
```

fixed the issue for me.

Clearly `require` and `import` treat the modules differently.